# Замена угловых скобок внутри элементов XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlparser

Как отловить и заменить угловые скобки внутри элементов XML-файла?
Парсить по закрывающим тегам?
Структура XML и названия полей заранее не известны, как и попадающиеся скобки, для примера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipe>
<recipe name="хлеб" preptime="5min" cooktime="180min">
   <title>
      Простой хлеб
   </title>
   <composition>
      <mainIngredient amount="3" unit="стакан">Мука <<Кубиночка>></mainIngredient>
      <ingredient amount="0.25" unit="грамм">Дрожжи <Минутка></ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1.5" unit="стакан">Тёплая(>35 С) вода</ingredient>
   </composition>
</recipe>
```

Comment: Починить генератор этого «XML». Потому что сейчас он невалидный.

Comment: Генератор не проверяет валидность, и к нему нет доступа. Структура становится невалидной когда в значения полей попадают строки, содержащие  угловые скобки. Это суть вопроса - как уже готовый файл распарсить и убрать служебные символы < >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как отловить и заменить угловые скобки внутри элементов XML-файла?

Можно обработать текст регулярным выражением...

```js
let data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipe>
<recipe name="хлеб" preptime="5min" cooktime="180min">
   <title>
      Простой хлеб
   </title>
   <composition>
      <mainIngredient amount="3" unit="стакан">Мука <<Кубиночка>></mainIngredient>
      <ingredient amount="0.25" unit="грамм">Дрожжи <Минутка></ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1.5" unit="стакан">Тёплая(>35 С) вода</ingredient>
   </composition>
</recipe>`
const re = /(<([a-z]+)[^>]*>)(.*)(<\/\2>)/gi
data = data.replace(re, (_, a, b, c, d) => {
  c = c.replace(/[<>]/g, '-')
  return a + c + d
})
console.log(data)
```

Или вот такой вариант...

```js
let data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipe>
<recipe name="хлеб" preptime="5min" cooktime="180min">
   <title>
      Простой хлеб
   </title>
   <composition>
      <mainIngredient amount="3" unit="стакан">Мука <<Кубиночка>></mainIngredient>
      <ingredient amount="0.25" unit="грамм">Дрожжи <Минутка></ingredient>
      <ingredient amount="1.5" unit="стакан">Тёплая(>35 С) вода</ingredient>
   </composition>
</recipe>`
const re = /(<([a-z]+)[^>]*>)(.*)(<\/\2>)/gi
data = data.replace(re, (_, a, b, c, d) => {
  return a + `![CDATA[${c}]]` + d
})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Всё бы ничего, но.. `(>35 С)` -> `(-35 С)`

Comment: @De.Minov, меняй на любой другой символ. Это вроде как очевидно...